# Can't create Image in PaperScript / Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, paperjs

I cant seem to create an an image such as `var imageObj = new Image();` in [Paperscript][1] for the HTML5 canvas.  Paperscript should be built on top of Javascript so I'm not understanding why it's not working.

@ Alex Wayne - No image pops up on my canvas..  If I change "script type="text/paperscript" canvas='canvas'"  to "script type="text/javascript" canvas='canvas'" the image comes back

@James - Can you show me a link to help me understand that better?

Comment: What, specifically, happens instead of what you expect?

Comment: Image is a javascript object, I'm guessing what you want is a Raster?

Comment: Show some code if you want help with this, otherwise no one has enough information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have to answer this with basic code from http://paperjs.org/tutorials/images/working-with-rasters/

// Create a raster item using the image tag with id='mona'
var raster = new Raster('mona');

// Move the raster to the center of the view
raster.position = view.center;

// Scale the raster by 50%
raster.scale(0.5);

// Rotate the raster by 45 degrees:
raster.rotate(45);